# How to add header data in XMLHttpRequest when using formdata?

Tags: javascript, http-headers, xmlhttprequest, form-data, mediafire

I'm trying to implement a file upload API, given here :

[Mediafire file Upload](http://www.mediafire.com/developers/core_api/1.4/upload/#upload_top)

I am successfully able to upload the *Post data* & *Get data*, but have no clue how to send the **x-filename** attribute, which is meant to be *Header data* as given in API guide.

My Code :

```
xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
var formData = new FormData();

formData.append("Filedata", document.getElementById("myFile").files[0]);

var photoId = getCookie("user");
// formData.append("x-filename", photoId);            //tried this but doesn't work
// xmlhttp.setRequestHeader("x-filename", photoId);   //tried this too (gives error) [edited after diodeous' answer]

xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function()
{
    alert("xhr status : "+xmlhttp.readyState);
}

var url = "http://www.mediafire.com/api/upload/upload.php?"+"session_token="+getCookie("mSession")+"&action_on_duplicate=keep";

xmlhttp.open("POST", url);
// xmlhttp.setRequestHeader("x-filename", photoId);   //tried this too, doesnt work. Infact nothing gets uploaded on mediafire.  [edited after apsillers' answer]
// cant get response due to same origin policy
xmlhttp.send(formData);
```

Comment: Could you give us the error text for `setRequestHeader`?

Comment: It is javascirpt, thus no error texts, script just stops executing, might be it is not allowed

Comment: Just to clarify, you mean there are no errors in your [browser's JavaScript console](http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/8525/how-to-open-the-javascript-console-in-different-browsers)?

Comment: @apsillers ohh, I never new abt [Javascript Console](http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/8525/how-to-open-the-javascript-console-in-different-browsers)    
Error : Uncaught InvalidStateError: An attempt was made to use an object that is not, or is no longer, usable. upload.php:42    
uploadAjax upload.php:42    
onclick upload.php:130

Comment: @apsillers line 42 is setrequestheader line & line 130 has a button with onclick attribute that calls the above code

Answer (score 129, accepted):

Your error

> InvalidStateError: An attempt was made to use an object that is not, or is no longer, usable

appears because you must call `setRequestHeader` *after* calling `open`. Simply move your `setRequestHeader` line below your `open` line (but before `send`):

```
xmlhttp.open("POST", url);
xmlhttp.setRequestHeader("x-filename", photoId);
xmlhttp.send(formData);
```

Comment: Got rid of error but, still not working.. Actually cant get response from mediafire due to same origin policy. Dunno what the problem is, could u plz check the [Mediafire API](http://developers.mediafire.com/index.php/REST_API#upload) & let me knw what the problem is, file was successfully uploaded to mediafire without this edit, now nothing is uploaded!

Comment: without that line file was being uploaded, but with default name!

Comment: that clears things up a bit. See [Understanding XMLHttpRequest over CORS](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13400594/understanding-xmlhttprequest-over-cors-responsetext/13400954#13400954). The same-origin policy allows "simple" requests to reach the client, and then decides if the client can read the results. "Non-simple" requests are verified with a "preflight" request before sending the actual request. Adding a non-simple header changed your request from simple to non-simple. In both cases, I assume you couldn't read the response from the server?

Comment: or for workaround can i change the name of uploaded file before sending it to mediafire??  Then i wont need to send extra parameter.

Comment: ohh good to know that adding headers makes the request non-simple.
 Thanks for help :)

Answer (score 38):

Use: `xmlhttp.setRequestHeader(key, value);`

Comment: I tried this too, javascript stops executing after this statement, doesnt work! 
(Will add this to my question)

Answer (score 2):

Check to see if the key-value pair is actually showing up in the request:

In **Chrome**, found somewhere like: `F12: Developer Tools > Network Tab > Whatever request you have sent > "view source" under Response Headers`

Depending on your testing workflow, if whatever pair you added isn't there, you may just need to clear your browser cache. To verify that your browser is using your most up-to-date code, you can check the page's sources, in **Chrome** this is found somewhere like: 
`F12: Developer Tools > Sources Tab > YourJavascriptSrc.js` and check your code.

But as other answers have said:

```
xhttp.setRequestHeader(key, value);
```

should add a key-value pair to your request header, just make sure to place it after your `open()` and before your `send()`