# How to capture No Access-Control-Allow-Origin error?

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, angularjs

I am using AngularJS, but I've encountered the same issue with JQuery and in plain JavaScript as well. If the remote server I am accessing sets Access-Control-Allow-Origin then either the `success` or `error` methods is invoked.

When there is no Access-Control-Allow-Origin neither of those is called and I can only see the error in the console. Is there a way to capture the 
`No Access-Control-Allow-Origin` error in my JavaScript code?

And just in case you are interested in a use-case, I am building a front-end for PyPi https://pypi.python.org/ There, you can get the information about packages in JSON format. (e.g. https://pypi.python.org/pypi/dspy/json ). Those requests set the Access-Control-Allow-Origin, but if I send a request for a package that is not on the server (e.g.  https://pypi.python.org/pypi/dspyz/json ) then I get No Access-Control-Allow-Origin and thus I don't get anything invoked in my JavaScript code.

**Update**

After some more experiments I found out that the `error` method was called it just threw an exception due to some issue with the code I used and that mislead me.

Comment: Of course, `error` gets called.

Answer (score 3):

This is not possible because of security reasons. Sniffing the users local network would be possible.

Further information [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25316393/keep-getting-no-access-control-allow-origin-error-with-xmlhttprequest).

Link credits to eithedog for his comment.

Comment: Does that mean that the JavaScript code does not know about the request being rejected? Is it just silently not answered as if it was a timeout?

Comment: Yes, I just tried it again. You get exactly the same kind of error object, when you listening on `xhr.onerror` wether it's a `timeout` or a `No Access-Control-Allow-Origin`. The only way you can distinguish these errors in a unsecure way is to track the time gone since you started the request.