# Access-Control-Allow-Origin denial despite CORS configuration

Tags: css, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, cors

I'm trying to load static assets (specifically CSS) from an Amazon S3 server and having trouble with CORS. My S3 CORS configuration looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<CORSConfiguration>
    <CORSRule>
    <AllowedOrigin>https://my.site.com</AllowedOrigin>
    <AllowedMethod>GET</AllowedMethod>
    <AllowedMethod>POST</AllowedMethod>
    <AllowedMethod>PUT</AllowedMethod>
    <AllowedHeader>*</AllowedHeader>
</CORSRule>
</CORSConfiguration>
```

I was under the impression that this would give me the green light, and it works in Chrome and Mozilla, but in Safari I still get the dreaded:

```
[Error] XMLHttpRequest cannot load https://my.static/files.css. Origin https://my.site.com is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Origin.
```

Are the other necessary configurations that I am missing? Is this a Safari problem that I can't really fix? On a semi-related note, does S3 need rebooted for changes to the CORS config to go into effect?

I've read [Understanding XMLHttpRequests Over CORS (responseText)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13400594/understanding-xmlhttprequest-over-cors-responsetext/13400954#13400954) and [How does Access-Control-Allow-Origin header work](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10636611/how-does-access-control-allow-origin-header-work) but those reference modifications to the CORS configuration that I believe I have already made.