# Access-Control-Allow-Origin error in Angular JS while accessing data from remote service

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I Have Service which is having the url of another computer, I am getting this error while accessing the response from my other computer using the Ip address..

```
$http({method : 'post',
        url : 'http://xxx.xxx.0.xxx:8080/hms/spring/user/users'
        data : ''}).then(function(response) {
                    $scope.patient_data = response.data;
                });
```

Getting this error:

```
XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://xxx.xxx.0.xxx:8080/hms/spring/user/users. Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://localhost:8080' is therefore not allowed access.
```

Comment: This is such an easy error to search. Please try searching before asking

Answer (score 0):

Access-Control-Allow-Origin is a [CORS (Cross-Origin Resource Sharing) header](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/cors/).

When Site A tries to fetch content from Site B, Site B can send an Access-Control-Allow-Origin response header to tell the browser that the content of this page is accessible to certain origins. (An origin is a domain, plus a scheme and port number.) By default, Site B's pages are not accessible to any other origin; using the Access-Control-Allow-Origin header opens a door for cross-origin access by specific requesting origins.

For each resource/page that Site B wants to make accessible to Site A, Site B should serve its pages with the response header:

```
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: http://siteA.com
```

Modern browsers will not block cross-domain requests outright. If Site A requests a page from Site B, the browser will actually fetch the requested page on the network level and check if the response headers list Site A as a permitted requester domain. If Site B has not indicated that Site A is allowed to access this page, the browser will trigger the XMLHttpRequest's error event and deny the response data to the requesting JavaScript code.

Non-simple requests:

What happens on the network level can be slightly more complex than explained above. If the request is a ["non-simple" request](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/cors/#toc-handling-a-not-so-simple-request), the browser first sends a data-less "preflight" OPTIONS request, to verify that the server will accept the request. A request is non-simple when either (or both):

using an HTTP verb other than GET or POST (e.g. PUT, DELETE) using non-simple request headers; the only simple requests headers are: Accept Accept-Language Content-Language Content-Type (this is only simple when its value is application/x-www-form-urlencoded, multipart/form-data, or text/plain) If the server responds to the OPTIONS preflight with appropriate response headers (Access-Control-Allow-Headers for non-simple headers, Access-Control-Allow-Methods for non-simple verbs) that match the non-simple verb and/or non-simple headers, then the browser sends the actual request.

Supposing that Site A wants to send a PUT request for /somePage, with a non-simple Content-Type value of application/json, the browser would first send a preflight request:

```
OPTIONS /somePage HTTP/1.1
Origin: http://siteA.com
Access-Control-Request-Method: PUT
Access-Control-Request-Headers: Content-Type
```

Note that `Access-Control-Request-Method` and `Access-Control-Request-Headers` are added by the browser automatically; you do not need to add them. This OPTIONS preflight gets the successful response headers

Access-Control-Allow-Origin: http://siteA.com
Access-Control-Allow-Methods: GET, POST, PUT
Access-Control-Allow-Headers: Content-Type
When sending the actual request (after preflight is done), the behavior is identical to how a simple request is handled. In other words, a non-simple request whose preflight is successful is treated the same as a simple request (i.e., the server must still send Access-Control-Allow-Origin again for the actual response).

The browsers sends the actual request:

PUT /somePage HTTP/1.1
Origin: http://siteA.com
Content-Type: application/json

{ "myRequestContent": "JSON is so great" }
And the server sends back an Access-Control-Allow-Origin, just as it would for a simple request:

Access-Control-Allow-Origin: http://siteA.com
See [Understanding XMLHttpRequest over CORS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13400594/understanding-xmlhttprequest-over-cors-responsetext/13400954#13400954) for a little more information about non-simple requests.

I believe it would help you to understand CORS issue and resolution better.